# Problema con navegación del header

Tags: html, css, nav

Hola tengo un problema con los nav del header, me pasa que quiero mover los links a la derecha pero nada me funciona, no hace nada con ningún código.

Este es mi código necesito mandar los nav a la derecha de todo dentro del header, ando necesitando su ayuda:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fbbc02;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.letraheader {
  font-family: 'Kdam Thmor Pro', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.logo img {
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.links {
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: font-size .5s ease-in;
  justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="./img/pelotafutbol.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <h2 class="letraheader">Mercado Futbol</h2>
  <nav class="links">
    <i class='bx bxs-hand'></i>
    <a href="">Opiniones</a>
    <i class='bx bxs-user-account'></i>
    <a href="">Crea tu cuenta</a>
    <i class='bx bxs-log-in'></i>
    <a href="">Ingresa</a>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

No te funciona funciona porque si usas flex y quieres que los elementos se distribuyan bien aunque flex ya hace un buen trabajo lo mejor es calcular los tamaños correctos, por ejemplo, trata de darle al logo, texto y nav un width y luego le aplicas el right, de esa forma funcionara correctamente, por ejemplo:

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    header {
        display: flex;
        background-color: #fbbc02;
        padding: 10px;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .letraheader {
        font-family: 'Kdam Thmor Pro', sans-serif;
        color: black;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30%;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .logo {
        width: 6%;
    }
    .logo img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .links {
        font-size: 16px;
        transition: font-size .5s ease-in;
        justify-content: end;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 64%;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 3s%;
    }
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/001/204/011/original/soccer-ball-png.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <h2 class="letraheader">Mercado Futbol</h2>
      <nav class="links">
        <i class='bx bxs-hand'></i>
        <a href="">Opiniones</a>
        <i class='bx bxs-user-account'></i>
        <a href="">Crea tu cuenta</a>
        <i class='bx bxs-log-in'></i>
        <a href="">Ingresa</a>
      </nav>

    </header>
```

Aqui le asigno un tamaño a los elementos y luego al nav solo le aplico un text-align: right; de esa forma sigues aprovechando flex sin necesidad de usar float.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En vista que ya tienes creada la clase `links` lo que podrías hacer es alinear la barra de navegacion en un bloque `display: inline-block` y posterior a esto agregarle la propiedad `width` para que te ocupe cierto tamaño de la pantalla, eso lo decides tu, yo le doy un 60% y por ultimo lo que tienes que hacer es alinear el texto hacía la derecha:

```css
 header {
            display: flex;
            background-color: #fbbc02;
            padding: 10px;
            align-items: center;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        
        .letraheader {
            font-family: 'Kdam Thmor Pro', sans-serif;
            color: black;
        }
        
        .logo img {
            height: 50px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        
        .links {
            text-align: right;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 60%;
            font-size: 16px;
            transition: font-size .5s ease-in;
        }
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/03/00/16/balloon-5799070_1280.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <h2 class="letraheader">Mercado Futbol</h2>
        <nav class="links">
            <i class='bx bxs-hand'></i>
            <a href="">Opiniones</a>
            <i class='bx bxs-user-account'></i>
            <a href="">Crea tu cuenta</a>
            <i class='bx bxs-log-in'></i>
            <a href="">Ingresa</a>
        </nav>

    </header>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!